# Adjusting UISlider thumb image

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uislider

So I've added a thumb image to my custom `UISlider` like this:

```
self.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "POITicker"), for: .normal)
```

But as you can see it's not centered. How can I adjust the image so that the the thumb is centered to the center of the circle?

[image]

Comment: You need to add as much "blank space" *below* the circle as is used by the triangle *above* the circle.

Comment: @DonMag I just tried this and no luck

Comment: Add a triangle under the circle.... see if you get the circle centered with up and down triangles.

Answer (score 2):

It's your custom slider, so override `thumbRect(forBounds:...)`; that's what it's for.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uislider/1621344-thumbrectforbounds

For example, you might say

```
override func thumbRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect, trackRect rect: CGRect, value: Float) -> CGRect {
    return super.thumbRect(forBounds: bounds, trackRect: rect, value: value)
        .offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -7)
}
```

except that you'd adjust the `dy` value by eyeball.

Answer (score 2):

One option, which also gives you a "taller" touch area for the thumb:

[image]

Obviously, use a transparent background instead of the green shown here.

[image]