# Change ThumbImage slider

Tags: swift, swiftui, slider, uiimage

I'm working in swift and I need to move the thumbImage of a slider like by default the image in centered but i need to move the image to the top.

I tried this but dind't work for me

```
let verticalOffset: CGFloat = -10
```

```
let resizedImage = customThumbImage?.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: verticalOffset, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0))
```

```
slider.setThumbImage(resizedImage, for: .normal)
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69590091/6257435